# Adding Model Attribute with MySQL later in project

Tags: mysql, django, migration, mamp

I have a working django project and I want to add a new model attribute. How do I do this?

Currently I have done

```
class Stream(models.Model):
    workingattributes = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    step = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

when I run 'python manage.py runserver' I receive a

```
DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'livestream_stream.step' in 'field list'")
```

I have gone into MAMP and accessed my database and added a new column 'step', but I receive the same error. Anyone have recommendations on how to add new attributes? THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html) (or something similar) to do a Schemamigration. Read the documents to see how to do it. It's quite easy, and will be very helpful later in your project (when you have lots of data in your database). The only other option (other than using another migration tool) is to drop the database and create it again, which would lose you all of your data.

Comment: I'm having trouble with South - 'Unknown command: 'schemamigration''     How do I create a new database, I don't care about keeping the old info?

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial? You need to install South, add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` (in `settings.py`), then do a migration. If you just want to delete your old database and start over, enter `MySQL`, and run the commands `drop database ____;`, followed by `create database ___;`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use South as per @Daniel Rosenthal suggestion, but the reason you are still receiving an error after creating the column is that the column you create should be named `appname_modelname` not just `model_name` so you need `foo_step`